# numpy.array_equal returns False, even though arrays have the same shape and values

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I have a very simple function, as shown below

```
def new_price(A, B, x):
    return np.linalg.inv(A @ B) @ x
```

These are the inputs I give it

```
A = np.array([
    [2, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 10]
]) 

B = np.array([
    [3, 3, 3],
    [2, 0, 8],
    [0, 5, 3],
    [0, 0, 10] 
])

x = np.array([ 84, 149, 500])
```

This returns the array `[ 1.  3.  5.]`. But, when I make the following equality check, it returns `False`

```
v1 = new_price(A, B, x)
v2 = np.array([1.0, 3.0, 5.0])
np.array_equal(new_price(A, B, [ 84, 149, 500]), np.array([1.0, 3.0, 5.0]))
```

I checked and the shapes and the types of both the arrays are same. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The are not exactly equal:

```
>>> new_price(A, B, [ 84, 149, 500]) -  np.array([1, 3, 5])
array([  2.84217094e-14,  -1.42108547e-14,   0.00000000e+00])
```

Better use `np.allclose()`:

```
>>> np.allclose(new_price(A, B, [ 84, 149, 500]), np.array([1.0, 3.0, 5.0]))
True
```

> Returns True if two arrays are element-wise equal within a tolerance.

You can adjust the relative and absolute tolerance.

Still true for really small values:

```
>>> np.allclose(new_price(A, B, [ 84, 149, 500]), np.array([1.0, 3.0, 5.0]),
                atol=1e-13, rtol=1e-14)
True
```

Found the limit:

```
>>> np.allclose(new_price(A, B, [ 84, 149, 500]), np.array([1.0, 3.0, 5.0]),
                atol=1e-14, rtol=1e-14)
False
```