# How to compare equality of two tuples that involve with list

Tags: python, numpy, unit-testing

found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580676/comparing-two-numpy-arrays-for-equality-element-wise) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48527910/numpy-array-equal-returns-false-even-though-arrays-have-the-same-shape-and-valu) but doesn't solve my issue.

I want to perform unit test by comparing two tuples as a whole, not element-wise.
The tuples involve with int and list of boolean. Length of the list varies in my real situation. For simplicity, i fix the length of list at 2 for demonstration purpose.
so the function i want to unit test gave output format look like this:

```
A = some_function(input)
where 
$ some_function(input)
> (array([ True, True]), array([ True, False]), 2)
```

I tried to unit test A by creating B, like so:

```
B = (np.array([True, True]), np.array([True, False]), 2)
```

I have tried the followings but both return False instead of True as I'd expect. Why? how can i fix it?

```
np.array_equal(A,B) 
> False
```

```
np.array_equiv(A,B)
> False
```

```
A==B

>ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-125-2c88eac8e390> in <module>
      1 A=_tokenwise_to_entitywise(ref,hyp)
----> 2 B== (np.array([True,True]), np.array([True,False]), 2)
      3 
      4 A==B

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with `A == B`?

Comment: These are tuples, by the way, not arrays

Comment: I can't replicate `np.array_equal(A,B)` or `np_array_equiv(A,B)` returning `False`. I got `True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> a
(array([ True,  True]), array([ True, False]), 2)
>>> b
(array([ True,  True]), array([ True, False]), 2)
>>> a==b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#75>", line 1, in <module>
    a==b
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use  a.any() or a.all()
```

The equality test compares element-wise. The ndarray comparisons return an ndarray.

```
>>> a[0]==b[0]
array([ True,  True])
>>>
```

As the error message states this can be ambiguous.  If you search SO for `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` you will find many Q&A's

```
>>> bool(a[0]==b[0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#78>", line 1, in <module>
    bool(a[0]==b[0])
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
>>>
```

Your first link almost got you there, you just need to apply `np.all` to each element's comparison.

```
>>> all(np.all(x==y) for x,y in zip(a,b))
True
>>> #or
>>> any(map(np.all,zip(a,b)))
True
>>>
```

I'll have to think a bit to see if there is a better way.

Answer (score -1):

I can't comment yet but, the answer above should work.

or you could create a function for reusability.

```
def equality_check(A, B):
    X = True
    if A==B:
        X = True
    else:
        X = False
    return X
```

Then you can run

```
print(equality_check(A, B))
```

on any variables, lists, arrays, tuples, etc

or you can create boolean objects as

```
x = equality_check(A, B)
print(x)
```

This lets you store that boolean value for later use.

Hope this helps.